# Bluetooth mouse on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 18.04

After updating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 my Bluetooth mouse MUST be reconnected everytime my computer locks or reboots.  It always connects, but doesn't stay connected when I lock the computer or reboot.  It used to stay an option and I only had to wake it up with a mouse click.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem here, but I haven't find a solution yet...

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390542 it seems that this could solve the issue.

Comment: Same problem here, mouse (pretty standard Logitech M535) was working fine in 16.04, but after upgrading to 18.04 it does no longer reconnect when waking my laptop up from sleep. The mouse also seems to disconnect at random times, it usually reconnects after power cycling the mouse. I tried the solution mentioned on the forum, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Works foe me with ThinkPad X1 Carbon and Lenovo Bluetooth Laser Mouse: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390542